# After making a bare repository clone of an existing repository, is it possible to treat the original repository as a clone of the bare repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

A Question: I have an existing git repository with a working directory.  I want to begin sharing this repository with a team.  I have done the following: `git clone --bare repo_dir repo_dir.git` and had the team clone the `repo_dir.git`.  Now I want `repo_dir` to stay up-to-date with any changes pushed to the bare repo.  The approach was to just remove the remote origin from `repo_dir.git` and add a remote origin to `repo_dir` pointing to the `repo_dir.git`.  That is:

```
cd repo_dir.git
git remote rm origin
cd ../repo_dir
git remote add origin ../repo_dir.git
```

I tried updating the original repo: `git pull origin master` and it seemed to work fine but I am concerned that there may be some other configurations that, left unchanged, will lead to weird behavior. Is it ok to treat this original repo as a clone of the bare repo or must I make other changes?  Does anyone have any insight here?

Thanks!

Comment: You may (or may not) want to set up the branch(es) in `repo_dir` as "tracking" (the ones in `../repo_dir.git`): `git config branch.master.remote origin && git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to treat this original repo as a clone of the bare repo or must I make other changes?

Yes: in a *distributed* VCS, any repo can be the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** of another.

The only thing to be careful (but not in your case), is the nature of potential *hooks* that you could trigger when pushing to a new upstream repo.
Since this bare repo is quite recent, this doesn't apply.